What is the name of this old horror movie?
From what I can remember, I saw it in the 80s. Husband and wife buys a house. Something happens to the wife and she turns into this fat scary lady who tries to kill him. He finally kills her and buries her in the back yard her and her hand crawls out and into the home and tries to kill him. One scene, the neighbor rings the doorbell and the man noticed the hand and tries to capture it so the neighbor wouldn't see it. At the end of the movie, the man is sitting on the couch, exhausted from finally killing the hand and the song "Happy Happy Birthday Baby" is playing. 

I also remember something going on with a closet in the house. When you open the closet, either you change into something scary or maybe it's a dark hole. One of the two.

